# The importance of design in a spring app

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, aop

I've been taking a look into using the spring framework for my java apps.

It is such a different way of looking at programming in general, i'm talking about DI and AOP!

The level of breaking the fundamental parts up into reusable components to me seems like a lot of work up front(in the design process). Im questioning the part of when I'll know its ready to get coding(this might just be in experience)

Guess I am looking at some tips? Where should you begin? It seems it has to be perfectly designed from the get go to avoid this tightly coupling scenario that seems so common amongst other applications I have worked with(not necessarily made them myself) When will I know its time to shoot my load and code?

Please don't tag this is a subjective or something I just want some honest and decent advice from the community.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "When will I know its time to shoot my load and code?". Uhm. What?

Comment: Is that inappropriate? - I mean just get to work, put pen to paper/fingers on keys

Comment: I would think the answer to this question would be the same as the answer to "The important of design", i.e. the same as if you weren't using this one library

Comment: I don't really have an answer per se, but it doesn't have to be perfect from a design perspective to avoid tightly coupling.  When you design, focus on the interfaces you want to use and avoid thinking about implementation details.  I love using white boards to flesh out ideas.  Otherwise diagramming can help if it gets overly complicated.

Comment: Just start right now and build a simple example app, that uses spring-mvc, hibernate, spring declarative transactions, and whatever other spring features look interesting to you. It'll ultimately be a throw away, but doing is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ive never seen an app that was completely designed (on the implementation level) up front.  On the contrary, refactoring is (well should be) part of the process, regardless of whether or not you use Spring.

Perhaps you are overcome by the scope of the Spring framework.  Don't be.  The main goal is to use dependency injection to invert control, and allow you to write simple POJOS to structure your app.  It doesn't make an app more complicated, it makes one simpler.

This is not to say that everything with Spring is strait forward - it isn't.  But you can learn the more complicated things as you go.

In response to your comment, think of the spring configuration as metadata for your class.  You cannot configure Spring with a class you have not defined.  Spring handles the creation and life cycles of the defined beans for you.  So if ClassA depends on ClassB, then when a ClassA gets created, the framework will create the dependencies (and inject them) for you.

Comment: A really nice answer thank you. I mean that is one of the reasons why interfaces are so powerful. However as for DI I am still slightly confused. I have just come across this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206770/dependency-injection-in-every-aspect-of-a-spring-app I believe I am in the same boat on this, how do you wire up objects that dont exist in order to avoid them being too highly coupled?

Comment: No, the objects exist as far as your code is concerned.Spring takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

When I went with Spring DI, I realized that I stopped spending so much time figuring out whether to instantiate objects, or look them up from some service or do something else to them.

You probably shouldn't go overboard with DI either. A good guideline would be to split app into beans at the "seams" where you would want to do unit tests. Similar approach - at the "seams" between application layers: data access, vs. business logic services, vs. UI.