# Dependency Injection in every aspect of a spring app?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am taking a look into Spring as a web framework, however I am needing a bit of help getting my head around DI.

The concept of objects getting constructed in the container on run time is such a new concept.

I am just wondering how this will reflect in a big application, would I have some modules doing work that are more highly coupled or should every object be initialised at runtime?

It all seems a little intensive to me, I mean say for example I have a CSV file data mining application that removes the data per row - each rows data is encapsulated in one of my own `CSVRow` objects for processing or whatever. These objects are instantiated whenever an Excel file maybe uploaded to the server. I don't know how many I will need to create?

I seem to be getting a bit lost, any clarity, an overview or some guidance would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to put it simply:

- use dependency injection for stateless classes that have logic (business logic, persistence logic, front-end logic)
- use `new` for value objects

Answer (score 3):

Broadly speaking, an application is made up of a collection of classes that implement the business logic.
Normally each object is responsible to obtain references of the objects it needs (and this object's dependencies).
I think it is obvious that this leads to:
1)  tightly coupled classes
2)  code hard to test since each object instantiates specific classes it depends on and if there needs to be a change, the code must be modified.
So using Dependency Injections the objects do not instantiate the dependent objects themselves but an "external component" provides the dependencies at the object creation time i.e. injects the dependencies into the objects.
So in your example, the idea is that you can have for example a CsvRow object instantiated by Spring (along with all its dependencies) and get an object whenever needed. It is also possible to switch to for example CsvRow2 object (another implementation) by just changing your configuration

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use DI for your CSV row abstraction.  Once you get the file, when you start parsing it, your code can create the CSVRow things as it goes.  You don't need to wire them up.

You certainly could if you wanted to.  You would grab your applicationContext and just get the beans by name.  You would want to do this if the CsvRow had dependencies that you wanted Spring to manage for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think of Spring as a way to create "singletons". When I want to guarantee there's only one instance of a class in the application, use Spring to create it. But, instead of being a traditional singleton with a static `INSTANCE` field or similar, it's a POJO with whatever constructors / setters you need. Spring creates the instance at runtime for you and makes sure that creation only happens once.